# Block does not show up in block list

Tags: blocks

recentpost.file

```
name = recentpost
description = A list of node with thumbnail
package = Liu's custom
core = 7.x
version = 1.0
files[] = recentpost.module
```

recentpost.module

```
/**
 * @file
 * Add thumbnail to each node
 */

function recentpost_block_info(){
  $blocks['recentpost'] = array(
    'info' => t('Recentpost'),
    'status' => true,       
    'weight' => 0,
  );
  return $blocks;
}



function recentpost_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  $block['subject'] = t('Node with thumbnail');
  $block['content'] = 'ssssssssssssssss';
  return $block;
}
```

I've created a sample module from scratch and can activate it in `admin->module`, but when I go to `structure->block`, the block I've just created doesn't show in the list no matter how many times I've cleared the cache both from drupal and the IE. Can anyone help me sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

**Always set region** (Until bug is fixed)

I believe this may be a bug in the code, it seems that is Status/region are toggled it causes problems, to guarantee that it shows for now make sure you set region

```
    function recentpost_block_info(){
      $blocks['recentpost'] = array(
        'info' => t('Recentpost'),
        'region' => BLOCK_REGION_NONE,
        'status' => true,       
        'weight' => 0,
      );
      return $blocks;
    }
```

The bug seems to be in the function "`_block_rehash()`" where it checks for `empty($block['status'])`

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your database:
DELETE FROM block WHERE module="modulename";

This will delete the rows in your database related to your block.

Comment: Wow this is what worked for me. Drupal seems to be caching stuff here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `hook_block_view` is incorrect.

You're declaring your *recentpost* block correctly in `hook_block_info`, but you're not telling `hook_block_view` which block to manipulate.

Try the following:

```
function recentpost_block_view($delta=''){
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {    
    case 'recentpost':
      $block['subject'] = t('Node with thumbnail');
      $block['content'] = 'ssssssssssssssss';
    break;   
  }

  return $block;
}
```

[`hook_block_info`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7)

[`hook_block_view`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7)

**EDIT**

I'm also assuming that the first part is from your `.info` file, and that the snippet above isn't taken in whole from your `.module` file.

Comment: Also, you don't need to declare `.module` files in your `.info` file.  That line should be removed.

Comment: The code you provided was just what I had used in my module,it cann't work so I removed the switch statement,and as of you provide me with that code,I paste it to my module but it still aren't working as before.I had done everything you told me and I can not think of anything wrong with this code , drupal 7.14 might have something to do with this issue?

Comment: Since the block_info function is correct,it should've shown in the block list but there's nothing out there.This code used to work in previous version of drupal

Comment: The top section of code is from your .info file, correct?  You've not put that in your module?

I'm using the code perfectly in 7.14.  The snippet I adapted was copied and pasted from a working module of mine.

Comment: Also, something else I've jsut noticed is that `status` should be assigned either 1 or 0.

Comment: It is from info.php file,neither 1 or 0 is working

Comment: Right, well, for starters that should actually be `MODULENAME.info`, not `info.php` - try reading the [Module Developers Guide](http://drupal.org/node/361112), there may be a problem with your whole module implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem caused by the delta. Example:

```
function approval_block_info() {
  $blocks['unpublished_nodes'] = array(
```

As you can see, my delta was unpublished_nodes. That was the problem! Block was not displayed. When I change this to my_unpublished_nodes, everything worked just fine.

Solution: Carefully choose your block names!

Comment: choose unique name?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I am guessing it's a drupal issue, more exactly a caching issue.
This happened on a fresh installed drupal installation.
Here is my hook_block_info():

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */

function essential_block_info() {
    $blocks = array();
    $blocks['cursul_zilei'] = array(
        'info' => t('Cursul zilei block'),
    );
    $blocks['imaginea_zilei'] = array(
        'info' => t('Imaginea zilei block'),
    );
    $blocks['animatie_interesanta'] = array(
        'info' => t('Animatie interesanta block'),
    );
    $blocks['news_feed'] = array(
        'info' => t('News feed block'),
    );
    return $blocks;
}
```

For some reason my blocks weren't appearing in the list so drupal rule no.1 popped in my head: "If something is wrong clear the cache". Did that but the issue didn't resolve, therefore I cleared the cache manually from the db and it worked.

Just empty all the tables that start with 'cache' in your db and you'll be fine.